# C# How to CLONE a DataSet inside if/else statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, dataset, clone

i would like to know (if its posible) how to CLONE a DataSet inside an if/else statement, i mean, i want to trigger a query search using a button, then pour that data into the cloned Dataset (that has the exact structure i want, table relations included) to correctly show search data in form. Here is the code:

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(); // A connection string...

    if (whatever)
    {
      whatever
    }
    else
    {
        OdbcDataAdapter SearchData = new OdbcDataAdapter(); //Query string...

        //now i need to clone a existing DataSet

        DataSet cloneSet = dataSet.Clone();

        //Then fill it with dat from query

        SearchData.Fill(cloneSet);
    }
} // end of button click event
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Existing dataset is a remote Database. It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to accomplish this?

Yes and you are already doing it. [`Clone()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) method does exactly the same thing ... creating a new dataset from the existing one with all the schema present. So in your case, below line `cloneSet` will have same structure as of existing `dataSet`

```
DataSet cloneSet = dataSet.Clone();
```

But, Why can't you use the existing dataset? why clone it? Moreover, `cloneSet` can't be used outside your event handler since it will loose it's scope. If you intend to use it outside button click event handler you might want to declare it globally.

Comment: Problem is that code does not work. Seems that .Clone() method cannot be called from inside if/else or even inside the btn_click event. Try yourself. I Mean i want to clone the datase only under X conditions, so i need to do inside the click event AND the if/else statement.

Comment: @FranMontserrat, no that shouldn't be. What error do you get while calling?

Comment: After using .Fill(cloneset), cloneset is still empty. I know because im using that cloneset as my form bindingSource.Datasource, and return no values.

Comment: @FranMontserrat, then your question is wrong. You don't need `Clone()` rather you need to use `Copy()` method like `DataSet cloneSet = dataSet.Copy();`